# Passing django view dictionary and variables to a iframe template in a template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two pages.

1) create_form.html , rendered with create_form view 
2) formatter.html , rendered with formatter view

I added formatter view in create_form.html with iframe.

```
<iframe src = "/formatter" width = "768" height = "500" frameBorder="0"> </iframe>
```

I pass a dictionary to create_form while rendering create_form.html. I can reach this dictionary in create_form view. But i need to pass this dictionary also to the formatter.html which is in an iframe in create_form.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't access context variables inside the `iframe`; that's because the iframe is rendered by a **separate** view function/class.

But you can use django's [include template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include) to accomplish what you want.

As mentioned in the docs:

> Include loads a template and renders it ***with the current context***. This is a way of “including” other templates within a template.

Comment: This solution can work in some situations. But my problem is the 2 html pages have different css and js versions. If i include them in one page the css and js cause conflict in some areas. So i am trying to keep the seperated with iframe but show them like one page.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I passed the dictionary as below to the iframed view. So i was able to print it in the iframed template.

In create_form.html :

```
<iframe src = "{% url 'formatter' tester=tester %}" width = "768" height = "500" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

In Urls.py :

```
url(r'^formatter/(?P<tester>[\w-]+)/$', formatter, name='formatter')
```

In views.py :

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def formatter(request, tester=None):
    return render(request, "formatter.html", {'tester': tester})
```

Comment: Not working for dictionaries. Above solution is only working for variables like strings. We can pass variables, but cannot pass whole dictionary inside iframe.